# Promise.all.then Not all code paths return a value

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following function that I want to return **Promise< number[] >**

```
async fetchCommentLines(commitDict: CommitDict): Promise < number[] > {
    if (GitCommentService.isLoggedIn()) {
        const commentLines = Object.values(commitDict).map(async commit => {
            // ...
            // do the job and return number[]
            // ...
            return lineNums;
        });

        Promise.all(commentLines)
            .then(commitLines => {
                return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], commitLines);
            });
    } else {
        return [] as number[];
    }
}
```

Firstly I got **"function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'"**

And then I added **undefined** (so return type becomes **Promise< number[] | undefined >**)

But I'm getting **"not all code paths return a value"** this time.

It seems I'm not considering a possible code path with below code

```
Promise.all(...)
.then(val => {return ...})
```

What I'm missing?

I also tried this

```
Promise.all(...)
.then(val => {return ...})
.catch(e => {return ...})
```

But it was not helpful

**Note:** My main purpose is to return **Promise< number[] >**, not **Promise< number[] | undefined >**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your branch with `Promise.all` never issues a `return (value)` statement. The `then` callback does, but not the code outside the `then` callback.

You probably want to `return` the result of `Promise.all().then()`.

```
    return Promise.all(commentLines)
//  ^^^^^^
        .then(commitLines => {
            return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], commitLines);
        });
```

Comment: My purpose with it was to flatten a `number[][]` into `number[]`

So `[[1,2],[3,4]]` into `[1,2,3,4]` 

I'll try the other ways you mentioned

Comment: @user3790180 - Ah! In that case, ignore me. :-) (I've removed that part of the answer.) You might look into [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-flatMap). It's at Stage 3 and already supported by Chrome and Firefox, easily polyfilled for others... :-) That would be `return Promise.all(commentLines).then(commitLines => commitLines.flat());`

Answer (score 2):

you should return the `Promise`

```
return Promise.all(commentLines).then(...)
//....
```

or wait for the promise and return the result object

```
let lines = await Promise.all(commentLines)
return [].concat(...lines)
```